# Choicelike consequence of compactness

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, axiom-of-choice

Could someone please elaborate on the [proof of Corollary 3.2.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactness+theorem#choicelike_consequences)?

Why does one need a total order *on $F$* if one is just interested in well-ordering each $F_x$ (in order to choose one element)? Also, a well-ordering on a finite set shouldn't be hard to find, the problem probably is to find a well-ordering on each of the possibly infinite many finite sets at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that if you have a family of finite sets whose union can be linearly ordered, then you can uniformly define "the minimum" from each of those sets, and thus have a section. And this is the catch: moving from "each set can be well-ordered" or "all sets can be well-ordered at the same time".

For example, even if $\Bbb R$ cannot be well-ordered, its finite subsets can be uniformly well-ordered, by taking the linear ordering they inherit from $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'd be happy to hear some constructive criticism.

Comment: First of all, if this is not answering your question, you may want to clarify better as to where you missing the point. Secondly, if you accept the axiom of choice, why bother with this question to begin with?

Comment: I am not sure that stating something like this "formally" is going to clarify anything.

Comment: I explained to you the proof. So I am not sure part you are missing. If you can point at the gap, I can close it, and that's fine.

Comment: @user7280899 - If being more formal helps, try actually *writing out a proof* without using the linear ordering on $F$ in detail. It'll be easy to see where it breaks down formally if you just really try to write out the set-builder form of the section.

Comment: @user7280899: $F$ is the union of all the $F_x$'s, because that's is how you define a function.

Comment: @user7280899: That is a separate proof. Every two linear orderings on a finite set are isomorphic, and are well-orders. But now I am confused. If you don't know these facts, why are you even reading that page? Even more so, if you believe the axiom of choice, why are you reading that page?

Comment: @user7280899: You fix a linear ordering on $F$, and then each $F_x$ has a minimal element, and no choice was used. This is exactly what is written in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: You take the pairs $(x,a)$ such that $x\in X$ and $a\in F_x$ and for all $b\in F_x$, $a\leq b$, where $\leq$ is the ordering on $F$. Perfectly definable.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: Thank you very much for your help! Now it is clear to me.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you for pointing out that F is the union of all the F_x's and the time you took to discuss my question.